# Windows phone bug - access denied to device camera

Tags: windows, titanium, appcelerator

I am facing an issue with the windows phone camera: I am not able to open it using the Titanium.Media.showCamera method. It returns a zero error code (access denied).

I've put all the necessary permissions in the app.xml (correct me if I am wrong):

```
<windows>
    <manifest>
        <Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10" xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest" xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities" xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10">
            <Capabilities>
            <DeviceCapability Name="webcam"/>
            <uap:Capability Name="picturesLibrary"/>
            </Capabilities>
        </Package>
    </manifest>
</windows>
```

I've been stuck on this issue for several days, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this code to ask Camera permissions first :: ?

```
    if (Ti.Media.hasCameraPermissions()) {
        takePicture();

    } else {
        Ti.Media.requestCameraPermissions(function(cameraArgs) {
            if (cameraArgs.success) {
                takePicture();

            } else {
                alert('Camera access denied.\nError: ' + cameraArgs.error);
            }
        });
    }
```

**Note that above code requires minimum Ti SDK 5.1.0**

Comment: Yes, but this method (hasCameraPermissions()) is not available on windows phone...

Comment: Docs says that it's available for Windows also from Ti SDK 5.1.0

Comment: I'm running the app wit the 5.5.1 SDK and it get this error: Ti.Media.hasCameraPermissions is not a function...

Comment: ALthought the doc says it is compatible with Windows as from 5.1.0 SDK...

Comment: Try with the latest SDK version 5.5.1 and you can also try with 6.0.0.RC version

Comment: Yes , but then I am not able to build on the windows device. I get this error: [ERROR] : Invalid "--device-id" value "0". Any idea?

Comment: Your device is not recognised by either Studio or your system. May be some USB config settings help

Comment: The device is recognised on my system. I can access the folders... What USB config are you thinking about? Thanks :-)